# How do I write this Rails scope that checks for a condition in an intermediary table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How can I write a scope on User that returns all addresses associated with that user (through orders) where the order.paid == true?

Notice that Order has multiple associated Address instances with different names, but the Address models are the same.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :shipping_address, :class_name => "Address", :foreign_key => :shipping_address_id
    belongs_to :billing_address, :class_name => "Address", :foreign_key => :billing_address_id
    belongs_to :user

    # the order table has a boolean 'paid' field
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :order
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
    # I want to create a scope here that returns addresses that belong to paid orders
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong but if you add a

```
 :has_many :addresses
```

to class Orders, I think*** it should give you back all the rails related to that user. I am just learning ruby on rails so apologize if this is wrong.